bash block script step pipeline no executing on a pipeline1 called from other pipeline2
i have a pipeline1 that execute a bash script block success and run ok,BUT when i invoke this pipeline1 from pipeline2 the bash script block didn't executed.
Other sh individual line commands yes run ok and it showed output but into block script not be are executing
Any idea?
I am referencing to this:
pipeline1
  steps { 
        script{
          sh "echo Hello1 world"
          sh '''#!/bin/bash
          sh "echo Hello2 world"
          <commands>
          '''
        }
    }

pipeline2
steps { 
            build (job: '../../folfer1/pipeline1', parameters: [ 
            ... 
            ], wait: true) 
} 

Then, the output on pipeline2 showed
            echo 'Hello1 World'
            echo 'Hello2 World'

but not executing sh block bash and not showed any error, only showed Hello1 world
sh "echo Hello1 world"
sh '''#!/bin/bash
sh "echo Hello2 world"
<commands>
'''

reproduction
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/folder1/pipeline1
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] ansiColor
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Executing playbook playbook1)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script (hide)
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Hello1 world
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ansiColor
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Resume:
if i invoke this pipeline1 from pipeline2 commands into block script not be are executing but, if I running pipeline1 alone the result and all executions are ok!)
Regards,
Edu < allways learning

What does it do instead of executing the step? Print anything in logs? Fails the pipeline? Just silently skips?

Hi Iterokun,
Just silently skips
Thanks for your questions

Never seen Jenkins skipping steps before, not unless there was an error on some previous step. How do you "invoke" one pipeline from another?

@Iterokun
                build (job: '../../folfer1/pipeline1', parameters: [
                   ...
                ], wait: true)
            }


If you add an echo 'Hello World' step after the allegedly skipped sh step, do you see 'Hello World' in the logs?

I added 2 echo before and after the sh block bash and both i showed them

Could you add the minimal repro to the question?

updated question with this testing, ty @Iterokun

Sorry, it's not a reproduction. Your pipeline1 would fail with an error because sh step is not allowed outside of node block.

update question again with i think that is a reproduction output. And How can i to do for sh step allow execution outside? ty @Iterokun

See that [Pipeline] sh in your log? The sh step was executed, but didn't print anything. Easy to confirm by adding an echo From Inside command at the very start of that script.

Hi @Iterokun, I detected by your idea witrh echo's testing workflow that only not execute a for statement located on sh block bash outside of it all execute ok. Updated question again :S thanks!

So, the sh step is executing. I believe you can close the original question.

Sorry, buddy, this is not an interactive troubleshooting session. You ask a question and if your original question is answered you close it and we all move on.

ok sorry, i will go to do it
Thanks for all

Ok, thanks to echo command I showed where pipeline reproduction is skipped execution code. Thanks @Iterokun
